# Why Intents are not preserved in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm testing my mobile phone how many intents can be created in parallel but only one is created...

This is my app manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="standard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".IntentExamples"
        android:exported="false"
        android:launchMode="standard"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

And this is the class where I do all the calls...

```
public class IntentExamples extends AppCompatActivity {

// Numbers of intents created
static int COUNTER = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intent_examples);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    // When a intent is created +1 to the counter
    COUNTER++;
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.intent_counter)).setText("NUMBER OF INTENTS: " + COUNTER);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.another_intent:
            Intent intent = new Intent(IntentExamples.this, IntentExamples.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish(); break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // When a intent is completely destroy, -1 to the counter
    COUNTER--;
}
```

The main activity just have a copy pasted code from the menu's code...

When I hit the item menu that creates another intent, in the TextView shows 1 intent created, I hit it again, shows 2 intents created and when I hit the button a 3rd time it got stuck in 2 intents created... I don't understand the reason why the counter doesn't reach 3 intents created or more.

Comment: Did you try to put logs in `onCreate` and `onDestroy` methods? Maybe `onDestroy` downgrades `COUNTER`.

Comment: When an intent is destroyed I want a -1 to the counter, my objective is to discover how many intents can be executed at the same time

Comment: Maybe answer is `2` :) I mean maybe when you create your third activity the first one is actually destroyed.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say when I turn my mobile it shows 1 instead of showing 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code from `onOptionsItemSelected()`

```
switch(item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.another_intent:
        Intent intent = new Intent(IntentExamples.this, IntentExamples.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    case android.R.id.home:
        this.finish(); break;
    default:
        return false;
}
```

There is no `break;` after `startActivity()`, so the `Activity` finishes. So eventually (not necessarily immediately!) `onDestroy()` is called and `COUNTER--` is executed.

Because the `Activity` has called `finish()`, it is not possible to reach it once more by pressing BACK - and this "misbehaviour" was what I could not explain in the first place. I was ready to believe that the Runtime would keep at most two `Activity` instances alive and store all the others in the BackStack. But not being able to go back? There had to be an explanation for this - and I'm kind of relieved I've found it :)

Now why does `COUNTER` show 1 instead of 2 after rotating the device?

That's because an orientation change (like all [configuration changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)) causes all `Activity` instances to be destroyed, and the one which was shown is instantly recreated.

Comment: @Bechma - no need for that :) And an interesting question. BTW the Activity (not the Intent) is the thing which is or is not destroyed. Intents are just a means of transferring information (between Activitys, Services, BroadcastReceivers...) And once you fix your error you will notice that onDestroy() is not called very often, but onSaveInstanceState() is - there aren't very many Activity instances in RAM simultaneously.